# Mysql query issue

Tags: mysql

I have two columns one is member_id and other is connection_member_id. I have to check whether if member and connection_member already inserted in db then don't insert it.

Trying to fetch some thing like this

```
SELECT * FROM `mlm_connections` mc 
LEFT JOIN temp_connections_members tcm 
ON tcm.member_id != mc.member_id 
AND tcm.connection_member_id != mc.connection_member_id;
```

Comment: Check the IF Exists clause.

Comment: Why do you need to check first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `mlm_connections` mc 
WHERE mc.member_id  NOT Exists (SELECT member_id  FROM temp_connections_members) AND    
      mc.connection_member_id NOT Exists (SELECT connection_member_id  FROM temp_connections_members)
```